# Need help inresilving the bug

Tags: asp.net, linq

How can i Remove this error. pls Help me in this...

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Linq.Model.usp_DisplayrecordsResult>' to 'System.Data.Linq.Link<Linq.Model.usp_DisplayrecordsResult>'   C:\Users\anu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Linq.DAL\DAL.cs  23  24  Linq.DAL
```

method in which error raised is as follows..

```
Linq.Model.DataAccessDataContext _DataAccessDataContext;
        public Link<usp_DisplayrecordsResult> DispPersons()
        {
            try
            {
                _DataAccessDataContext = new Linq.Model.DataAccessDataContext();
                var query = _DataAccessDataContext.usp_Displayrecords();
                List<usp_DisplayrecordsResult> Listresult = new List<usp_DisplayrecordsResult>(query);
                return Listresult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you intended to use the `Link` structure as return type. If you change that to `List` it will compile:

```
public List<usp_DisplayrecordsResult> DispPersons()
```

Comment: Hello,how to resolve 'Linq.BD.BD.DispPersons()': not all code paths return a value C:\Users\anu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LinqSample1\Linq.BD\BD.cs 12 47 Linq.BD   Thanks Again

Comment: @asif: You get that error when it's possible that the code exist from the method without returning a value and without throwing an exception. With the code above that is not possible, so you must have changed something (other than the return type).

Comment: You are Correct that with above code that is not possible, I got this error with Some other Method,Thanks Again For the nice Explanation  u gave..